# It's possible to use a function to check if the condition is true or false in do...while?

Tags: javascript

Here's my code. What i want to check is that all the elements processed in the `do`, or not. The reason is that in the `kategoriak` array, only one of it's object has `szint: 1`. But it's possible that this element is at the end of the array. I want to do the process until every element has a `szint` which is not 0. But it don't matter. My question is that what am i doing wrong at the `while`? The code should work, but it's an infinite loop. Any ideas?

```js
do{
    kategoriak.forEach(elem => {
        elem.child.forEach(child => {
            kategoriak.forEach(ell => {
                if(child === ell.id && elem.szint !== 0){
                    ell.szint = elem.szint + 1
                }
            })
        })
    })
} while(
    () => {
      kategoriak.forEach(elem => {
          if(elem.szint === 0){
              return true
          }
      })
      return false
    }
)
```

Comment: would be nice if you provide the `kategoriak` array, so we can know which kind of value is inside that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give `while` a function, but `while` isn't going to call your function. It will regard a function as a truthy value and hence continue endlessly. You'll have to call your function yourself. But really, that is nonsense, you just have to use an expression which results in `true` or `false`, in this case [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is what you're looking for:

```
do {
   ...
} while (kategoriak.some(elem => elem.szint === 0));
```

(Whether this is the best approach to this problem in the first place I dare not say.)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `while(...)` you define a function but not call it. Thus, the function expression itself is the condition, which is always true. You need to also call your function. i.e.

```
do{
    ...
} while(
    (() => {
      kategoriak.forEach(elem => {
          if(elem.szint === 0){
              return true
          }
      })
      return false
    })(); // Notice the parentheses we use to call the function
)
```

An even better way to implement this would be using `Array.prototype.some`. It is a method that returns true when some of the elements satisfy the given function.

```
do {
    ...
} while (kategoriak.some(elem => elem.szint === 0))
```